# permissions for external luks disk

Tags: 16.04, permissions, mount, luks

I set up an encrypted external disk with:

```
sudo fdisk /dev/sbXX
sudo cryptsetup luksFormat -c aes-xts-plain64 -s 512 -h sha512 -y /dev/sdXX
sudo cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/sdb1 NAME
sudo mkfs -t ext4 -m 1 -O dir_index,filetype,sparse_super /dev/mapper/NAME
```

that works fine, but the disk is always mounted by root user. I know how to change that on my computer, but when I plug the disk to another computer it has to be changed there again.

Is it possible to set the external disk in any way to be not mounted by root?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the options `-o umask=file-permission,uid=your-user,gid=your-group` when mounting your disk.

Comment: As explained, my question is, if it possible to change something ont the external disk(!) to have it always mounted by the normal user. As it is usual for non encrypted disks.

Comment: A solution here :  https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/115326/access-to-mounted-luks-partition-by-non-root-user